# In a MERN app, if you have a app.get('/') on your server and a <Route path=/' > on your client, which one will trigger first or take priority?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Say you have a React client with a nodejs express backend. On the server you have a route set up such that app.get('/') serves a Home.html. On the React side you have react-router-dom set up like

```js
<Route path='/' component= { NotHome } />
```

What file will be served/shown to the user, Home or NotHome?

Comment: your index page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between server-side routing and the client-side routing.

1. If you are making a standard HTTP request for the page (e.g. you type the URL in your browser's address bar), the **server-side** routing will take effect (e.g. serve you `Home.html`)
2. But *if* your `Home.html` then references the JS containing the `<Route />` tag, **client-side** routing takes effect. *react-router-dom* will render the NotHome component in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The server route will take preference, in a react app using express, your main server file should have a single route like this:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
})

app.listen(8000, '0.0.0.0', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  console.log('Listening on 8000')
})
```

The app.get('/*') is a catch all so that every get request e.g every address in the address bar of your browser will serve the index, which will in turn serve your bundle.js and render components based on your

Hope this helps.

Lloyd